# Is there any API or service to notify us when Chrome browser gets updated

Tags: google-chrome

We want to run all our test cases to be running against the new version of Chrome whenever it is released

So we are looking into a service which helps us say the Chrome browser got updated, so that we can get the latest Chrome and test our test cases to make sure everything is working.

Is there any tool, service, or API which helps us check for the updates of Chrome browser and informs us.

Answer (score 1):

All Chrome releases (all release channels) are posted in this blog: https://chromereleases.googleblog.com/

You can use standard RSS / Atom tools to keep up to date with its posts.

Alternatively, you can subscribe to release notes by email with https://inthecloud.withgoogle.com/chrome-release-notes/opt-in.html - but I assume it would only be about stable releases.

Finally, for an API-based approach, look at the [VersionHistory API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/versionhistory/)